# Why can't I get string input?

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop, char, scanf

I was trying to simulate stack concept, and this is my code, blasts errors everywhere, from

- the very first `scanf`,
- to everywhere referring `char*` variables,
- and eventually the stack pointer (I named it `towerIndicator`) doesn't change at all.
- And then every typed input is somehow screwed: if I type '+314' to add 314 to the stack, it eventually add 3144, if all the problem above were somehow prevented while compiling.

gcc doesn't inform me any usable error message so I don't get where to go at all. Desperately requiring help here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const int towerHeight = 32;
    int tower[towerHeight];
    int towerIndicator = 0;
    /*
    printf("%i개의 정수를 담을 수 있는 스택을 만들었습니다.\n", towerHeight);
    printf("- '+'를 붙여서 정수를 담습니다.\n");
    printf("- '-'를 입력해 정수를 빼냅니다.\n");
    printf("- '?'를 입력해 스택을 확인합니다.\n");
    printf("- '0'를 입력해 작업을 종료합니다.\n");
    printf("명령을 입력해주세요.\n================================\n");
    */
    char* command;
    char* kindOfCommand[1];
    char* actualCommand;
    while(1) {
        printf("> ");
        scanf("%s", command);
        printf("%s", command);
        strncpy(*kindOfCommand, command, 1); kindOfCommand[1] = '\0';puts("#");
        strncpy(actualCommand, command+1, strlen(command)-1);puts("$");

        switch(**kindOfCommand) {
                int i;
            case '+':
                if(towerIndicator<towerHeight) {
                    tower[towerIndicator] = atoi(actualCommand);
                    towerIndicator++;
                    printf("현재 %i개의 값이 있습니다.\n", towerIndicator);
                } else printf("더 이상 넣을 곳이 없습니다.\n");
                break;
            case '-':
                if(towerIndicator>0) {
                    towerIndicator--;
                    printf("%i\n", tower[towerIndicator]);
                    printf("현재 %i개의 값이 있습니다.\n", towerIndicator);
                } else printf("더 이상 빼낼 값이 없습니다.\n");
                break;
            case '?':
            default:
                printf("[");
                for(i=0; i<towerIndicator; i++) {
                    if(i==towerIndicator) printf("[%i]", tower[i]);
                    else printf("%i", tower[i]);
                    if(i!=towerIndicator-1) printf(" ");
                }
                printf("]\n");
                break;
        }

        if(**kindOfCommand=='0') break;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have plenty of *undefined behaviors* in you code, because you have pointers that doesn't point anywhere. When you define a local variable and don't initialize it, its value will be *indeterminate*, using that uninitialized variable leads to said UB. For example, lets take your `scanf("%s", command)` call. *Where* will `scanf` write the string it reads? Where `command` points of course, but if `command` doesn't point anywhere, where will the data be written then?

Comment: So I tried to initialize them as 'NULL', I get errors about that too. Will add these error in the question soon.

Comment: I think you need to take a couple of steps back, and go through a pointer and array tutorial.

Comment: But 'Pointers that's not pointing anywhere', I didn't thought about this way ever! Thanks for kind of inspiration about pointers.

Comment: @Dinir If you've never thought about pointer initialization, and what it means, then you really can't have read much about C. Or whatever you read was really bad. Get K&R, and read it.

Comment: @Dinir [this](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/) might clean things up to you.

Comment: How about allocating memory for your strings and other stuff?

Comment: I just didn't thought that way because I thought when a character variable is declared to a value it becomes constant so I couldn't change them after.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have another question then, if I get the first `scanf` out of the `while` and comment all the while loop part, it grabs input without any error successfully. Why it's possible in this case, though it's same that pointers are still pointing nowhere?

Comment: @Dinir That's the thing with undefined behavior, sometimes it *seems* to work. The operative word here is "seems", what really happens is that you write the string into some seemingly random memory location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few modifications required here

loosely fixed may be in for a lot more fixes

```
//    char* command;    // <-- initialize this, failure in scanf other wise
      char command[120] ;
```

assuming you are looking for a single character, don't complicate code

```
//    char* kindOfCommand[1];  pointer not required
          char kindOfCommand;
```

since you are using strncpy down somewhere

```
//    char* actualCommand; // <-- initialize this
    char actualCommand[126];
```

and the kindOfCommand code change

```
//        strncpy(kindOfCommand, command, 1);
          kindOfCommand = *command;// since you are taking single character
          puts("#");
```

some more at switch

```
switch( kindOfCommand ) {
```

and while breaking

```
if( kindOfCommand == '0' ) break;
```

Also return before end

```
return 0;
```

Comment: Will try these changes asap and edit the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I applied changes from kkk's answer, and getting input now works well.

```
char command[11];
char kindOfCommand;
char actualCommand[10];
while(1) {
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%s", command);
    kindOfCommand = *command;
    memset(actualCommand,0,sizeof(actualCommand));
    strncpy(actualCommand, command+1, strlen(command)-1);

    switch(kindOfCommand) { ... }
    ...
    if(kindOfCommand=='0') break;
}
return 0;
```

}

I needed to solve the input getting screwed. It was because when `actualCommand` receives a new string from `command` and it's shorter than previous received string, the last few characters of the string was still remaining in `actualCommand`. So I put a `memset` to reset the variable every time the while loop loops. It's not a pointer, so `sizeof()` could do the work. Otherwise I should've to use `strlen()` to tell `memset` the length.